# IntelliJ idea support for React.js

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13

I am currently using a licensed copy of IntelliJ idea 13.1. It doesn't seem to support `React.js` files.

I tried downloading intellij Idea 14.1, even this is not supporting React.js.

Is webstorm the only Idea IDE which supports React.js? I am using groovy on grails, java along with react.js, but these seem to be unsupported in Webstorm.

Is there any way I can use a single IDE for all three?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

React.js support is available in Idea 14. Do you have react.js available in your project? The normal way to get completion for API methods is providing the corresponding .js file to Idea - see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/07/how-webstorm-works-completion-for-javascript-libraries/.
Note also that you need to set JavaScript Language Version to 'JSX Harmony' in Settings/Languages&Frameworks/JavaScript to get JSX syntax correctly recognized.

Comment: Can we add JSX Harmony in Intellij 13.1?

Comment: No. Old versions are not patched to include features introduced in newer versions.

Comment: Even with JSX Harmony selected, I'm finding that IDEA 14 doesn't properly understand JSX.   In the react-native getting started example ("AwesomeProject") IDEA complains about "expected statement" at the end of the only top level JSX element in the code (the `View`)

Comment: It seems Intellij now auto suggests changing to `React JSX` as the Javascript Language Version